# fabric object constructor not creating cacheCanvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Fabric js 2.2.4 fabric object constructor not creating cacheCanvas.
where as in 1.7.8 there is a check for cacheCanvas and creating one.

```
  initialize: function(options) {
        if (options) {
            this.setOptions(options);
           }
          },


    initialize: function(options) {
        options = options || { };
        if (options) {
           this.setOptions(options);
        }
        if (this.objectCaching) {
          this._createCacheCanvas();
          this.setupState({ propertySet: 'cacheProperties' });
        }
      },
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking whether or not the check is required?

Answer (score 0):

Well i have been removing that. The reason behind it is that you may want to create 300 objects and render 1, it does not make sense to create a canvas at initialization. 
The canvas will be created at the first render, when needed, or you can still call the function manually.